# Behavior async await console application vs. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, deadlock

I am quite new to async await. I think I understood the example of the console application. When transferring the identical code to the WPF, there is a deadlock and I do not know exactly why.

```
// All as expected
// Output:
// LongOperationAsync Start
// Before task.Wait();
// LongOperationAsync End
// After task.Wait();
// Result: 4711

class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Task<int> task = LongOperationAsync();
        //Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("Before task.Wait();");
        task.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("After task.Wait();");
        var result = task.Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task<int> LongOperationAsync() {
        Console.WriteLine("LongOperationAsync Start");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("LongOperationAsync End");
        return 4711;
    }
}
```

and here is the blocking WPF code:

```
// WPF handler Output:
// LongOperationAsync Start
// Before task.Wait(); => Blocking

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Task<int> task = LongOperationAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine("Before task.Wait();");
    task.Wait();
    Debug.WriteLine("After task.Wait();");
    var result = task.Result;
    Debug.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
}

private async Task<int> LongOperationAsync() {
    Debug.WriteLine("LongOperationAsync Start");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Debug.WriteLine("LongOperationAsync End");
    return 4711;
}
```

Comment: The code blocks in both cases. Both examples are bad

Comment: In "async world" you should **never** do any `task.Wait()`'s or `task.Result`'s.

Comment: There is too much information to this to answer. this is a broad topic, all i can suggest is to keep doing more research. read about synchronization contexts, read about deadlocks, look up blogs by stephen cleary, and make use of google, you'll get there.

Comment: I think you can read this post https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Although advising to read more is fair advice, I think we can do better. Panagiotis posted almost exactly the code I was about to and I think showing the "right" code is useful.

Comment: @A5000: `I am quite new to async await.` I recommend starting with my [async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and then [async best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

The code blocks in both cases. Both examples are bad. Neither executes asynchronously.

The *correct* Console code would be :

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before LongOperationAsync");

    int result = await LongOperationAsync();

    Console.WriteLine("After LongOperationAsync");
    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The equivalent WPF code would be :

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Before LongOperationAsync");

    int result = await LongOperationAsync();

    Debug.WriteLine("After LongOperationAsync");
    Debug.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
}
```

`async` is syntactic sugar that allows the use of the `await` keyword. `await` *awaits* asynchronously for an already asynchronous operation like `Task.Delay()` to complete, without blocking the original thread. When that asynchronous operation completes, `await` resumes execution in the original synchronization context. In the WPF application's case, that's the UI thread. That's what allows updating the UI after an `await`.

`async void` is only meant for event handlers, like `button2_click`. In all other cases `async Task` should be used. `async void` methods can't be awaited and the application can't know whether they completed or not.

Comment: You can just await the task. var result = await LongOperationAsync();

Comment: @Andy I know. I had to start *somewhere* with the code though. The OP is confused about more fundamental issues at this point

Comment: Indeed. I thought it best to highlight that the Task isn't some sort of class or object though.

Answer (score -1):

In your example you can modify your button-click to async. Your Task is blocking because you never start him, you can never pass the "wait()" call without starting the task.

Below the modified button click method.

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = await LongOperationAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
}
```

Comment: The task is already started. The actual asynchronous task is the one generated by `Task.Delay()`. `await` doesn't start anything, it awaits already executing tasks